# How to use Import Xml feature in EPPLUS or other excel generation library?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, xml-import

I was reading in some very old posts that the XML importing feature is going to be implemented in EPPLus. Is it currently implemented? 
How can I Import data to a excel document that has a XML mapped to its cells. I can't use the interop services, because the excel file is big and I use many technics from EPPLUS library to fill it with data. Or should I rewrite all this fillings by Interop library?

Answer (score 0):

xlsx files are xml-based spreadsheets.  As it says on http://epplus.codeplex.com/, "EPPlus is a .net library that reads and writes Excel 2007/2010 files using the Open Office Xml format (xlsx)."  It's fast, it's not Interop, and it doesn't require that Office be installed.

Comment: Ok but how can actually do it? All I need is provide xml data to xlsx that has XML mapping(through DEVELOPMENT menu)